# mmenu counter or search not working in submenu/child records

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, vb.net, mmenu

I am using the mmenu (http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/).  I get the menu items from a datalist using sql queries for the parent menu  and the child menu.  I use the parent records to get the child menu items in a For Each process.

***.aspx.vb page**  This loads the records into memory.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    _ReportMasters = CType(Application("ReportMaster"), List(Of ReportMaster))
    _ReportMasterSubReports = CType(Application("ReportMasterSubReport"), List(Of ReportMasterSubReport))
    RenderMSRows()
    End Sub
```

Once the records are loaded I place them in the menu like this:
***.aspx.vb page still**

```
 Private Sub RenderMSRows()

        Dim ReportName As String
        Dim SubReportName As String
        Dim ReportNamesub As String

        Dim HTMLString As String = ""
        Dim ulString As String = "<ul data-role=" & Chr(34) & "listview" & Chr(34) & ">" & vbCrLf

        HTMLString = HTMLString & ulString
        For Each p In _ReportMasters
            ReportName = p.Report_Name

            HTMLString = HTMLString & "<li>" & vbCrLf
            HTMLString = HTMLString & "<span title='" & ReportName & "'>" & ReportName & "</span>" & vbCrLf
            HTMLString = HTMLString & "</a>" & vbCrLf
            HTMLString = HTMLString & "<ul>" & vbCrLf
            HTMLString = HTMLString & "<li>" & vbCrLf

            For Each sr In _ReportMasterSubReports

                ReportNamesub = sr.Report_Name
                SubReportName = sr.Sub_Report_Name

                If ReportNamesub = ReportName Then
                    HTMLString = HTMLString & "<a href=''title='" & SubReportName & "'>" & SubReportName & " </a>" & vbCrLf
                End If
            Next

            HTMLString = HTMLString & "</li>" & vbCrLf
            HTMLString = HTMLString & "</ul>" & vbCrLf
            HTMLString = HTMLString & "</li>" & vbCrLf
        Next

        HTMLString = HTMLString & "</ul>"

        Me.MenuBar.Text = HTMLString

    End Sub
```

**Then on the *aspx page:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#my-menu").mmenu({
                "classes": "mm-light mm-zoom-panels mm-slide ",

                "counters": true,
                "header": {                                         
                    "add": true,
                    "update": true
                },
                "searchfield": {
                    "addTo": "panels",
                    "add": true,
                    "search": true,
                }

        });
          </script>  

    </head>

    <body> 
    <div id="page">
    <div class="header FixedTop">
        <a href="#my-menu" onmouseover: title="Click To Open Document Menu"></a>             
    </div>                       

    <!-- The menu -->
    <nav id="my-menu" >       
        <ul>            
            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="MenuBar"></asp:Literal>          
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I apply the search feature it will work in the parent menu panel but not in the child/sub menu.
When I apply the counter feature it shows "1" for each count of child records that belong to the parent.  Some have a lot of children and some have few.  But the count on all of them reads "1". 
Anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anyone have any help with this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the UL and LI elements needed to be place in the right order.  The search and counter are working throughout five levels in the mmenu.